# delimited by end-of-file with OpenCV

Tags: c++, bash, opencv, eof

When I run this script, I get this warning.

```
./my.sh: line 8: warning: here-document at line 8 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `nameofpicture.txt')
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ -o crop crop.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

g++ -o recog recog.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

./crop

while read line

do

echo "$line" |./recog

done <<"nameofpicture.txt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `<<something` indicates the start of a *here-document*.
But most probably that's not what you wanted to do here,
but use a single `<` for input redirection from a file.

You probably meant to write the look like this instead:

```
while read line    
do   
    echo "$line" | ./recog
done < nameofpicture.txt
```

This loop passes each line from the file `nameofpicture.txt` to `./recog`.

Most probably you don't actually need a loop,
could redirect the input from the file directly to the program,
without a loop:

```
./recog < nameofpicture.txt
```